# Replace value in unordered list (html) + JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

D1
                D2
                D3

I need to change just the values between `<span>`  and `</span>` D1, D2, D3 with JQuery, with new values like X1,X2,X3 with JQuery.

Comment: FYI `UL` is *unordered list*. not unsorted list. :)

Comment: @Reigel: does it make a difference :p ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$('#navigation').find('span').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text(function(i, curr){
         return curr.replace(/D/, 'X');
    });
});
```

That would fit exactly your example.

Comment: why do you do var $this = $(this); ?

Comment: @dublintech: well, since I only need to access the outer `this` once its not mandatory to cache it. But in generell its best practice to cache values (especially jQuery objects) like so, if you need to access them more than once.

Comment: in addition to my previous comment I would add *...or within another function (child) scope*.

Answer (score 3):

`$('#nav-d1 span').text('X1')` would change `<span>D1</span>` to `<span>X1</span>`