# Populate menu with a text file eg text.txt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, database

I am trying to build a kiosk on a local machine only. I'm planning to use JavaScript to make the menu lists functional. Here is my html code example.

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
        <li class="current">
            <a href="#a">Area1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#aa">John's Store </a>
                    </li>
                        <li class="current">
                            <a href="#ab">Katy's store</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="current"><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#aba">Watermelon</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#abb">Apple</a></li>

                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            <a href="#">Catherine's Store</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pear</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>

                                </ul>
                        </li>

                </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Area2</a>
                <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Peter</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Rockmelon</a></li>


                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lynda</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Strawberry</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Jackfruit</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>

                                </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
            </li> <!--current-->

    </ul> <!--sf-menu-->
```

The person who is going to update/change the menu(which is going to be massive) is going to use a simple text file eg notepad - .txt (for certain reasons). Is there any way to update the menu items with a simple text file? Can I use a JavaScript or jQuery plugin/code?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using .get:

```
  var textFile = "SCHEME://DOMAIN/FILENAME.txt";        
  jQuery.get(textFile, function(textFileData) {             
      //Parse file and populate menu based on specs.   
      //textFileData will have the text      
    }
```

If you want the text back for each line you can do (assuming the names are separated by a newline):

```
   var EachLineInTextFile= textFileData.responseText.split("\n");         
   for (var i = 0, len = EachLineInTextFile.length; i < len; i++) 
   { 
     //This will give you each name from here you can put the name where you want it
   }
```

A sample would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var textFile = "http://localhost/MyDomain/Menu.txt";
        jQuery.get(textFile, function (textFileData) {
            var EachLineInTextFile = textFileData.responseText.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0, len = EachLineInTextFile.length; i < len; i++) {
                STORE_TO_REPLACE = EachLineInTextFile[i];
                //STORE_TO_REPLACE: I would have to the entire format of your file to do this.
            }
        })
    });           
</script>
```

From here, if you need help replacing the values in your list take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509466/replace-value-in-unordered-list-html-jquery)

Or, if you want to replace them all you can use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through your list.

Comment: Hi NgM, thanks for your fast reply! Sorry I'm new to jQuery, can you explain the code more in details? How is the code above connected to the menu list? For example, if my menu html is like      <ul><li>John</li><li>Katy</li><li>Catherine</li><li>Peter</li></ul>. I'd like the menu list to be populated from the members.txt (which has no code but people's names.) So someone can update the txt file only to upload the updated names.Thanks heaps!

Comment: What is the format of the text file?  Is it a name then a newline then a name?

Comment: It can be formatted anyway, but the way you said sounds good. My main goal is that no code for the person who is going to update the menu with a text file. Because there will be hundreds members/names, and under each member/name there will be products list as well. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to show you how to get each name line by line.  From here, you will just need to put the names in your list.  I gave you a link to how you would go about doing that as well.

Comment: Sorry NgM, I'm a bit slow on this, do you think Jquery will work the code I provided? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it will work.  You just need to get your format setup and learn a little bit about how to iterate through lists and you should have it working in no time.  First make sure you have the list in a format that is static and then build it up from there.  Take a look at the examples I gave you and links and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks you so much NgM, I will give it a go. You are so nice to help me out, I hope one day I can be like you to help other people. Thanks again, and have a nice weekend. Cheers, S:)